# How much is each type of chip worth in Poker Night At The Inventory?

Tags: poker-night-at-the-inventory

Soon I'm going to be getting custom Poker chips printed and since I love the Poker Night games I would like to have my chips worth the same as the chips in the Poker Night games. All I can remember is that Red = $1000.

I wish I could check it myself so you guys don't have to however my desktop recently broke and I can't afford to get a new one at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Chip denominations are:

- Green: 100
- Blue: 500
- Red: 1000

[image: In-game screenshot]